# Low quality thumbnails in listview VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, listview, thumbnails

I use VB.net

I use ListView to view 50*x thumbnails(.jpg) at the left to the items.

But instead of 32bit high quality thumbnails, ListView lowers them to 8bit or 16bit(not sure).

Here's the code

```
Private Sub afterprocessed()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim imlTemp As New ImageList
    Dim dirFiles() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("backend\communicate\thumbnails")
    Dim _imgList As New ImageList
    Dim imgSize As New Size
    imgSize.Width = 50
    ListView1.SmallImageList = _imgList
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    For Each dirFile As String In dirFiles
        Dim imgFilename As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dirFile)
        Dim img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(dirFile)
        Dim imgImage As Image = Image.FromFile(dirFile)
        'Dim imgHeight As Integer
        'imgHeight = imgImage.Height
        imgSize.Height = imgImage.Height
        _imgList.ImageSize = imgSize
        _imgList.Images.Add(img.Clone)
        ListView1.Items.Add(imgFilename, count)
        count += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

And the quality is noticably low. Compared to original JPG

Any advice? I'd greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the original and the low-quality versions?

Answer (score 1):

You need this.

```
this.ListView1.SmallImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem one time and I found out it was being caused by using the `ImageList.ImageSize` method, which seems to use a poor resizing algorithm. I resolved it by ensuring all the images I used were already the correct size on disk before loading them. But if that's not an option for you it shouldn't be too difficult to [resize them](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_resize.html) *before* adding them to the ImageList.

Comment: Thanks! I completely get what you mean. But which line should I change to listview *not resize when adding? Thanks again :D

Comment: It's not the `ListView` but the `ImageList` that's the problem. get the images the right size *before* adding them so you don't have to use the `ImageSize` method.